# Jquery sortable and default class?

Tags: jquery, user-interface

In jquery sortable they use this class alot:

```
ui-state-highlight
```

Now nowhere in the documentation does it say that when this class is added what happens or differs when you do or don't use it, anyone know?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

hello that class is essentially used on hover effects in the jquery ui , you can play around with its properties here : http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/